# 'frmSolicitudes' es tipo, que no es valida en el contexto indicado

Tags: c#, formularios, eventos, clase, metodos

estoy iniciando en este mundo de la programación y por eso ahora me encuentro con un error, por tal motivo acudo a ustedes para recibir ayuda sobre esto.

Tengo una clase con el siguiente método:

```
public void InicialLoad(frmSolicitudes obj, frmActividadSolicitudes objj)
    {
        objj.lUsuario.Text = obj.txtUsuario.Text;
    }
```

Entonces desde el evento Load de mi formulario quiero llamar este método:

```
private void frmActividadSolicitudes_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        clsMetodo obj = new clsMetodo();
        obj.InicialLoad(frmSolicitudes, frmActividadSolicitudes);

    }
```

Pero me esta saliendo este mensaje, la verdad no tengo idea en que estoy fallando, muchas gracias por su ayuda.

> 'frmSolicitudes' es tipo, que no es valida en el contexto indicado

Comment: Hay varias guías de estilo para C# pero en general, los nombres de las funciones y las clases deberían empezar con mayúsculas (*PascalCase*) y las variables con minúsculas (*camelCase*). Raramente encuentres algo escrito en *snake_case*. [Más información](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/coding-style/coding-conventions).

Comment: Gracias @Mateo, voy a tener muy presente esta información.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error:

> es tipo, que no es valida en el contexto indicado

indica que debes pasar una instancia de `frmSolicitudes`:

```
private void frmActividadSolicitudes_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    clsMetodo obj = new clsMetodo();
    frmSolicitudes frm = new frmSolicitudes(); //* crea una instancia
    obj.InicialLoad(frm, frmActividadSolicitudes);

}
```

Comment: Jorge muchas gracias. Fue de mucha ayuda tu respuesta.

Comment: Excelente @AndresGiraldo saludos!